# ajaxtoolkit modal popup Child window should return row value of gridview to the parent page

Tags: asp.net, window, parent-child, modalpopupextender

i'm new to ajax, i'm using ajaxtoolkit modalpopup here's the case

using an image button in a girdview on the parentpage modalpopup(child) is opened which has a girdview, i want to return the vale of the row of gridview from the childpage to the parent page textbox, modalpopup panel is on the same parent page .

Help me out...how to overcome this problem,

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste code, also modal pop up and controls will be the same page, so you can access directly, please paste code where you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use javascript

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "Key", "window.open('popupnew.aspx?QueryString "', 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=500,height=300,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=200,left=250')", False)

create a globel variable that you want to use in parent page in popup
after using variable clear it